# R WebScraping Getting Extra Text when using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get sold dates from eBay using R and RVest web scraping

The url is [url](https://www.ebay.com/sch/Star%20Wars%20%20BARC%20Speeder%20Bike%20Trooper%20Buzz%20-2009%20-Red%20-Obi-wan%20-Kenobi%20-Jesse%20-halmark%20-Funko%20-Pop%20-Black%20-snaptite%20-model%20-30th%20-Saga%20-Lego%20-McDonalds%20-McDonald%27s%20-Topps%20-Heroes%20-Playskool%20-Transformers%20-Titanium%20-Die-Cast%20-2003%20-2004%20-2005%20-2006%20-2007%20-2008%20-2012%20-2013%20%28Clone%20Wars%29&LH_Sold=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_dmd=7&_ipg=200&LH_Complete=1&LH_PrefLoc=1)

literally

https://www.ebay.com/sch/Star%20Wars%20%20BARC%20Speeder%20Bike%20Trooper%20Buzz%20-2009%20-Red%20-Obi-wan%20-Kenobi%20-Jesse%20-halmark%20-Funko%20-Pop%20-Black%20-snaptite%20-model%20-30th%20-Saga%20-Lego%20-McDonalds%20-McDonald%27s%20-Topps%20-Heroes%20-Playskool%20-Transformers%20-Titanium%20-Die-Cast%20-2003%20-2004%20-2005%20-2006%20-2007%20-2008%20-2012%20-2013%20%28Clone%20Wars%29&LH_Sold=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_dmd=7&_ipg=200&LH_Complete=1&LH_PrefLoc=1

The full xpath to the first item sold date is: `//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]`

If I use that and then html_text() to this path, I get nothing.  `character(0)`

When I remove the spans, and add the POSITIVE node, I get the date, but also a bunch of extra text.

R code:

```
readHTML <- url %>%
            read_html()

    SoldDate <- readHTML %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div') %>%
        html_nodes("[class='POSITIVE']") %>%
        html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
"SoYlPd N Feb 316,Z RM9USI2021"
```

I should get:

```
"Feb 16, 2021"
```

[image: View from Safari]

Comment: The html does not always appear as per your image; at other times (e.g. the first time I visited the page) the node identified by `.s-item__title--tagblock__COMPLETED .POSITIVE` had child span nodes. It looked like you could possibly grab the appropriate _visible_ nodes from that by use of class/partial class value; however, the html changed before I had time to write the css pattern to finish testing. I guess try to have an offline copy to work from and write logic to test if that top level node has children and do one pattern if yes, otherwise just use the target node.

Comment: I get `SoldDate` as `"Sold  Jan 11, 2021"` using your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 great answers with more detail specifics on the issue here:
[Rvest Split Data by Class Name where the class names change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575062/rvest-split-data-by-class-name-where-the-class-names-change?noredirect=1#comment117694541_66575062)