# Rvest Split Data by Class Name where the class names change

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm web scraping sol eBay data using Rvest.

Recently, eBay has started injecting hidden text into the readable text - see the image and scraped data.

Here is a URL example - you may or may not get the interlaced text:
[Example URL](https://www.ebay.com/sch/Star%20Wars%20Black%20Series%20%20-POTF%20-POTF2%20-POTFII%20-Vintage%20%20Boba%20Fett%20Han%20Solo%20%28SDCC%2CSan%20Diego%2CCon%29%20Carbonite%20-Walgreens%20-3.75%20-3%2F4%20-Connexions%20-Die%20-Lot%20-Topps%20-Sideshow%20-1%2F6%20-1%2F12%20-AFA%20-UKG%20-Custom%20-Signature%20-Lego%20-Funko%20-Pop&LH_Sold=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_dmd=7&_ipg=200&LH_Complete=1&LH_PrefLoc=1)

XPath to a line item

```
//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[1]
```

XPath I use to get all lines

```
//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li/div/div[2]
```

I need the text from `s-a4v02P` and that text aggregated by line item.

I get something like the this:

`"So2ld  Mar 8,D1 2021JUI"       "KSold  MQaUr2V 3,E 20R2KC1R"` and so on

Question is, How can I just get `"Sold Mar 8, 2021"       "Sold Mar 3, 2021"` and so on?

Code I've have so far:

```
readHTML <- url %>%
        read_html()
    
    Title <- readHTML %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li/div/div[2]/a/h3') %>%
        html_text()

     SoldDateTop <- readHTML %>%
         html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li/div/div[2]') %>%
         html_nodes("[class='s-item__title--tagblock ']") %>%
         html_nodes("[class='POSITIVE']") %>%
         # html_nodes("[class='s-8kjgi5']") %>% <-- this class name changes
         html_text()
```

[image: Example of the "hidden" text]

Comment: I remember commenting on this before `The html does not always appear as per your image; at other times (e.g. the first time I visited the page) the node identified by .s-item__title--tagblock__COMPLETED .POSITIVE had child span nodes. It looked like you could possibly grab the appropriate visible nodes from that by use of class/partial class value` for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404144/r-webscraping-getting-extra-text-when-using-rvest). Can that question now be closed? Also, is this still behaviour intermittent as it was before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine which tags are shown and which are hidden, there is a “style” element on the page with the display/hidden keys.

Using **rvest version 1.0.0**

```
library(rvest)
page <-read_html(url)

#find stype tags
styles <- page %>% html_elements("style") %>% html_text2()

#get the "display inline" key
#Assuming it is always the first style element of the second style node 
displayInline <- gsub("(.*?) \\{.*", "\\1", styles[2])

#find nodes of span with both class and role specfied
parent <-page %>% html_elements(xpath=".//span[@class='POSITIVE' and @role='text']") 

#retrieve the dates
sapply(parent, function(p) {p %>% html_elements(displayInline) %>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = "")})

[1] "Sold  Mar 8, 2021"  "Sold  Mar 3, 2021"  "Sold  Feb 27, 2021" "Sold  Feb 22, 2021" "Sold  Feb 20, 2021" "Sold  Feb 19, 2021" "Sold  Feb 5, 2021" 
[8] "Sold  Feb 4, 2021"  "Sold  Feb 3, 2021"  "Sold  Jan 31, 2021" "Sold  Jan 27, 2021" "Sold  Jan 22, 2021" "Sold  Jan 10, 2021" "Sold  Jan 3, 2021" 
[15] "Sold  Jan 1, 2021"  "Sold  Jan 1, 2021"  "Sold  Dec 30, 2020" "Sold  Dec 25, 2020" "Sold  Dec 22, 2020" "Sold  Dec 20, 2020" "Sold  Dec 11, 2020"
[22] "Sold  Mar 3, 2021"  "Sold  Jan 27, 2021" "Sold  Dec 25, 2020"
```

Comment: Nice. I noticed something similar in their prior question.

Comment: Thank you!  This solution works great.  I also apprecaite the detailed comments.  I'm very novice with rvest.

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach but based on observation that the variable part of the class value is length 6 for visible classes so you can extract the appropriate visible class value from the css style instructions

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

get_sold_date <- function(nodelist, visible_class){
  nodelist %>% 
    html_nodes(paste0('.POSITIVE span.', visible_class))  %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
      paste(collapse = '')
}

get_visible_class <- function(node){
    stringr::str_extract(node, '(s-[a-z0-9]{6})')
}

page <- read_html('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=Star%20Wars%20Black%20Series%20%20-POTF%20-POTF2%20-POTFII%20-Vintage%20%20Boba%20Fett%20Han%20Solo%20(SDCC,San%20Diego,Con)%20Carbonite%20-Walgreens%20-3.75%20-3/4%20-Connexions%20-Die%20-Lot%20-Topps%20-Sideshow%20-1/6%20-1/12%20-AFA%20-UKG%20-Custom%20-Signature%20-Lego%20-Funko%20-Pop&LH_Sold=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_dmd=7&_ipg=200&LH_Complete=1&LH_PrefLoc=1')
listings <- page %>% 
  html_nodes('#srp-river-results .s-item')

visible_class <- get_visible_class(page %>% 
                                     html_node('style[type="text/css"]') %>% 
                                     html_text(trim = T))

dates <- map(listings,  get_sold_date,  visible_class)

print(dates)
```

Also, means you can probably ignore extracting the appropriate class and use a filter function of some sort based on length of class being 8 i.e. `html_nodes('.POSITIVE span') %>% html_attr('class') %>% map(nchar) == 8`. I will have a look at that later today.

Comment: Thank you!  This solution works great.  I also apprecaite the split out of the functions.  I'm a novice R developer and like to see the style flexibility.

Comment: you are more than welcome :-) I was thinking to try and write the last thought I had about testing just the class length but that may be for tomorrow.